# How to create a dictionnary whose key:value pairs are the values of two different lists of dictionnaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value, lemmatization

I have 2 lists of dictionnaries that result from a pymongo extraction.

A list of dicts containing id's (string) and lemmas (strings):

`lemmas = [{'id': 'id1', 'lemma': 'lemma1'}, {'id': 'id2', 'lemma': 'lemma2'}, {'id': 'id3', 'lemma': 'lemma3'}, ...]`

A list of dicts containing id's and multiple words per id:

`words = [{'id': 'id1', 'word': 'word1.1'}, {'id': 'id1', 'word': 'word1.2'}, {'id': 'id2', 'word': 'word2.1'}, {'id': 'id3', 'word': 'word3.1'}, {'id': 'id3', 'word': 'word3.2'}, ...]`

As you can see, the two lists of dictionnaries are of different length, as there are multiple words associated with each id, but only one lemma.

My goal here is to **obtain a dictionnary whose key:value pairs correspond to word:lemma values for the words and lemmas that have the same id.** This way, i can replace every word for the corresponding lemma in a text that i am analyzing. For example:

```
word_lemma_dict = {'word1.1': 'lemma1', 'word1.2': 'lemma1', 'word2.1': 'lemma2', 'word3.1': 'lemma3'; 'word3.2': 'lemma3', ...}
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

The best i could achieve was to use 2 for loops, but it's not very "pythonistic":

```
id_lemma_dict = {}
word_lemma_dict = {}

for dico in lemmas:
    id_lemma_dict[dico['id']] = dico['lemma']  # create id:lemma dict from list of dicts

for dico in words:
    word_lemma_dict[dico['word']] = id_lemma_dict[dico['id']]

print(word_lemma_dict)
```

Comment: Can you please add quotes to your strings such that your data can be copied and pasted into a Python interpreter? Also is `lemmas` strictly increasing w.r.t. the id-key, with no numbers missing?

Comment: You can use dict comprehensions: `id_lemma_dict = {dico['id']: dico['lemma'] for dico in lemmas}`

Comment: `.update()`, read the documentation

Comment: @timgeb I just added the quotes, sorry.  I used numbers in the strings like "word1.2" as an example, but in my code they are actually words like "chocolate", i just can't publish the real lemmas and words list of dicts for confidentiality reasons.

Comment: @nonDucor good idea, are list comprehensions less complex than for loops in python?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "less complex", but in some cases they may have a slight speed advantage. Testing with a 10,000 long `lemmas` dictionary*, in my machine the one liner takes 865 us, while the for loop takes 969 us (12% more). *The artificial lemmas dictionary: `lemmas = [{'id': f'id{i}', 'lemma': f'lemma{i}'} for i in range(10000)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option with comprehensions:

```
lemmas = [{"id": "id1", "lemma":"lemma1"}, {"id": "id2", "lemma":"lemma2"}, {"id": "id3", "lemma": "lemma3"}]
words = [{"id": "id1", "word": "word1.1"}, {"id": "id1", "word": "word1.2"}, {"id": "id2", "word": "word2.1"}, {"id": "id3", "word": "word3.1"}, {"id": "id3", "word": "word3.2"}]

lemmas_dict = {item["id"]: item["lemma"] for item in lemmas}
word_to_lemma = {word['word']: lemmas_dict[word['id']] for word in words}

print(word_to_lemma)
```

Output:

```
{'word1.1': 'lemma1', 'word1.2': 'lemma1', 'word2.1': 'lemma2', 'word3.1': 'lemma3', 'word3.2': 'lemma3'}
```

Comment: Thank you @TomerAriel ! That's the kind of code i was looking for.

Comment: @TomerAriel, your `get_lemma` function is very inefficient, especially with large `lemmas` and `words` lists. It is better to create two dictionaries before (since dictionary look-up is essentially O(1)).

Comment: @nonDucor True, I assumed for some reason that we are dealing with a small number of items, but there's no reason to make such an assumption.
I've updated the answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out!